# Ambiguous BunifuTextBox issue in Bunifu.UI.WinForms namespace

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, bunifu

I am encountering an issue in my VB.NET project where the BunifuTextBox is causing an "ambiguous" error in the Bunifu.UI.WinForms namespace. The error specifically mentions:

```
Error BC30560 'BunifuTextBox' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Bunifu.UI.WinForms'.
```

I've tried several solutions, including checking references, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, and ensuring there are no duplicate controls in the Designer. However, the problem persists.

Here are some additional details:

I'm using Bunifu.UI.WinForms version 4.1.1.0.
There are 253 errors just because of the textbox.

I suspect there might be a conflict with BunifuTextBox from different versions or conflicting references. How can I resolve this "ambiguous" error and get BunifuTextBox to work correctly?

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Additional Information:

Bunifu.UI.WinForms version: 4.1.1.0
Visual Studio version: 2022

I know my question is pretty dumb to ask, sorry about that.

Edit: I still don't know how, I checked and there are no duplicate references
[image]

[image]

Comment: In your project, you have a class or an item that has the same name BunifuTextBox

Comment: That looks like far too many references.  Remove them all, except Bunifu.UI.Winforms.1.5.3